# Sort folders by date in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a directory that contains folders.Folder are created daily.Naming convention are based on the date it created e.g 20191029. My requirement is to get the latest 7 folders created. I am using below code but it doesn't seems give me the latest 7 folders. I get random 7 folders not sorted by date.

```
int x = 7;
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Temp");
var folderlist = dir.GetDirectories().OrderByDescending(p=> dir.CreationTime).Take(x).ToList();
```

Comment: `p=> dir.CreationTime` --> `p=> p.CreationTime` ?

Comment: @theduck you should have made that an answer!

Comment: @AustinTFrench, I believe those fall under typo.

Answer (score 2):

Your delegate should read:

`p => p.CreationTime` rather than `p => dir.CreationTime`